# Appending list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists, List 1 and List 2 comprising of 12 lists each.

I want to create a new list of lists (List 3) which joins the lists at each corresponding index of List 1 and List 2.

For example the first list in List 3 would be composed of List1[0] + List2[0]....

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Write a loop from 0-11 and add each element from the source lists to the target list?

Comment: You didn't think identifying the language would be relevant?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in a specific language?

Comment: Python sorry, (First timer)

Comment: See [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 1):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the two lists into a single list of tuples. Then use a list comprehension to combine the tuples however you want (in the question you asked for a list of values combined using the `+ operator`).

It should be clear how you can change this for any object type/operation:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
C = [x + y for (x,y) in zip(A,B)]
print(C) # [5,7,9]
```